# Laravel select table fields by using variables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to fetch selected fields from my tables in laravel for that I assign my table fields in a variable. But always it gives me some database query error, here I added my code for that. This working fine when I use direct fields instead of them assign into a variable

```
$selectedfields = "'table1.*', 'table2.*','table3.column'"
$data = DB::table('table1')
->select($selectedfields)->get();
```

Comment: please add error too

Comment: this will give you more clue https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#specifying-a-select-clause, also it looks here only table1 is present put you are selecting table2 & table3,

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax

Comment: I am using join here

Comment: you need to join table also

Comment: The issue is laravel add an extra inverted comma in my fields when I use them by variable

Comment: why you wanna use varaible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DB:raw](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions):

```
$selectedfields = 'table1.*, table2.*, table3.column';
$data = DB::table('table1')
->select(DB::raw($selectedfields))->get();
```

You might need to join table as well.

Answer (score 0):

your query should be like this

```
$data = DB::table('table1')
        ->join('table2','table2.id','=','table1.id')
        ->join('table3','table3.id','=','table1.id')
        ->select('table1.*','table2.*','table3.*')->get();
```